# How to get the line number in Python regex findall method

Tags: python, regex, findall

Is it possible to return the line number of regex findall method results in Python?

```
import re

s="""The
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog
"""

print re.findall('the', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
```

Expected Result: Will return line 1 and 7.

Is this possible without reading the text line by line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the regex engine has no concept of textual positions.

Comment: You can use finditer and can get match position but  afaik line no in regex is not possible.

`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='The'>`
`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(31, 34), match='the'>`

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this question. Why do you not search before asking?

Comment: Hi Tomalak, this is not a duplicate of question above. Would like to have a solution without looping line by line.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate... getting line numbers using finditer or findall without enumerating lines hasn't been addressed in the "duplicated" answer. I was going to post a solution but I can't till this is reopened

Comment: hi there, i know this question is closed but has anyone found an answer to this issue? i am trying to utilize re.findall to utilize its speed when searching using capture groups, but i realized i need to also grab the line numbers. i could iterate through the resulting list but that is no different from reading the file line by line totally defeating the purpose